# How do I hide connected/disconnected users in a IRC channel on mirc?

Tags: irc, mirc

In busy IRC channels there's a lot of connections/disconnections taking place. They are cluttering the IRC chat, how can I turn these messages off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Goto Tools
2. Goto Options
3. Goto +IRC
4. Click Events Tab
5. For joins, parts, quits, and kicks put hidden.

[image]